# android - application architecture what is the best?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, architecture

I am new on android programming, just did one app so far. After it's completed, I start to think about the architecture of android application.

In my app, I use `Activity` as Controller similar and `setContentView` to add layout View, this one is working and when it switch to another View, commonly I will use another Activity, or `ViewFlipper` or multi View in the same `Activity`, switch them by using `setContentView` method.

Now I am thinking is it good to change this architecture to this one -

Activity

Controller

View - Layout XML

Controller class is independent from Activity, so it will be like this -

```
class Controller {

    public View view;

    .....

    // logic to deal with view operation
    public void init ()
    {
    }
}
```

Activity will be like this -

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ControllerOne c0 = null;
    ControllerTwo c1 = null;

    .....

    protected void switchView (Controller c)
    {
        setContentView (c.view);
        c.init (); // or something else to restore states of this controller
    }
}
```

I don't know if this one is fine for android app architecture, or is there any good ideas about android app architecture? Thanks.

Comment: i hope MVP is a better structure for android as the view and activity can not be independent

Comment: Just think Activity is consuming a lot resource, so maybe we can reduce its quantity would be better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to ignore Android's MVC architecture. An activity class acts as a controller. But if you want to achieve something like using more than 1 controller for an activity, you should see Android's [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Thanks will check it and if any questions will ask u later.